# 503 service unavailable- Is there any issue with my ingress.yaml file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

Please bear with me. I may sound silly. But, I am very new to K8s and don't know much about writing its yaml files.

I have deployed one Spring Boot application as a pod to k8s cluster via its helm chart. When I access any URL of the application from pod's terminal using curl, I get a success response. but, when I access it from my laptop or browser, I get 503 service unavailable error. I have no idea what is happening. My senior says its an ingress issue. But, the helm install ran perfectly and pod came up as well.

Below is my ingress.yaml file.

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "my-service.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if and .Values.ingress.className (not (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion)) }}
  {{- if not (hasKey .Values.ingress.annotations "kubernetes.io/ingress.class") }}
  {{- $_ := set .Values.ingress.annotations "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" .Values.ingress.className}}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.19-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
{{- else if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace | quote }}
  labels:
    {{- include "my-service.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- if and .Values.ingress.className (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion) }}
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.className }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
          {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Below is the trace I get on my laptop's cmd terminal when I run curl from there.

```
*   Trying 10.210.228.31...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-server.corp.xyz.com port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my-server.corp.xyz.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: disabled server certificate revocation checks
* schannel: verifyhost setting prevents Schannel from comparing the supplied target name with the subject names in server certificates.
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 186 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 186 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my-server.corp.xyz.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my-server.corp.xyz.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 4096
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: encrypted data length: 4022
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4022 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my-server.corp.xyz.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 957
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4979 length 5046
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 93 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my-server.corp.xyz.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 274
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 274 length 5046
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my-server.corp.xyz.com port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> POST /api-htmplortal/authenticate HTTP/1.1
> Host: my-server.corp.xyz.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 73
>
* upload completely sent off: 73 out of 73 bytes
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 469
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 469 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 440
* schannel: decrypted data added: 440
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 440 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 440 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 440
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
< Server: nginx/1.17.10
< Date: Fri, 18 Jun 2021 14:09:45 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 198
< Connection: keep-alive
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
<
<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.10</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host my-server.corp.xyz.com left intact
```

Comment: There's conditionals relying on values that we do not know in your Helm chart. Share the output of `kubectl get ingress -o=yaml`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that. Had to learn about all the stuff that was going in. Finally, when I run the above with my namespace, I could find out that I had the same backend URL configured for two different services.

Comment: Good to hear you resolved it!

Comment: @KnockingHeads Also glad that you've managed to resolve your issue. Please provide the answer to the question you've posted so you will indicate that you've resolved your issue.

Comment: @DawidKruk, Thanks for pointing out. I had rather added it as a comment. But, in addition, I have added the answer in details as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a configuration issue. I was actually running different pods and I had helm charts of all. To spin up all the pods, I had a helm of helms which included all the helms as subcharts. The ingress in the question is the one from the parent/main helm chart.

To run the parent helm, I had a shell script which would provide environment properties to the subcharts of the parent chart.

Now, I had two helm subcharts: i.e. old-service and new-service. My requirement was that I needed to spin up only one based on a flag value. The new service was an upgraded version of the old service, so to not update the UI endpoint for accessing the services, I tried keeping the backend for both subcharts as same (thinking that since only one pod would spin up -> I was keeping replicaCount as 0 for pod which was not starting from my shell script) as below:

```
--set old-service.ingress.hosts[0].paths[0]="/proxy-service-${NAMESPACE}(/|$)(.*)" \
--set new-service.ingress.hosts[0].paths[0]="/proxy-service-${NAMESPACE}(/|$)(.*)" \
```

But, it turns out. It cannot be done. It appears that kubernetes reads configuration rather than pod running or not.

To resolve it, I kept the above two backend for new-service and old-service different and provided dynamic endpoint environment property to UI subchart based on which service was going to be up on the basis of flag value.

```
--set ui.proxyUrl=https://${LOAD_BALANCER}/${proxyUrl}-${NAMESPACE} \
```